# Can't emit signal in Android

Tags: android, qt

I have this signal in my project;

```
void sendImage(cv::Mat &imgMat, QImage &imgQImage);
```

Project compiles on both Mingw and Visual Studio but when i try to build for Android, i get "error: no matching function for call to imageReader::sendImage(cv::Mat&, QImage)" error.

I tested my pro file on different project, try clean/run qmake/clean/rebuild, remove cv::Mat from signal but nothing worked.

What can be the problem?

Edit;

```
#ifndef READERMANAGERQMLINTERFACE_H
#define READERMANAGERQMLINTERFACE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

#include "readermanager.h"
class ReaderManagerQMLInterface : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ReaderManagerQMLInterface(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~ReaderManagerQMLInterface();

    readerManager rManager;

private:

signals:
    void reqIm();

public slots:
    void sendImage(QImage &imgQImage);
};

#endif // READERMANAGERQMLINTERFACE_H
```

imageReader;

```
#ifndef IMAGEREADER_H
#define IMAGEREADER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QImage>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include <QDir>
#include <QFile>

#include <opencv/cv.h>
class imageReader : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit imageReader(QObject *parent = 0);
        ~imageReader();
        imgHelpers imHelpers;

    signals:
        void sendImage(QImage &imgQImage);
    public slots:
        void requestImage();
        void setFrame(int frameID);
        void loadImage(QString fileName);
    }
```

I'm emitting signal like this;(in case my mat2Image function causes the problem, i tried both)

```
void imageReader::requestImage()
{
    images.at(currentImageID).copyTo(this->currentImage);
    processImage(currentImage);
    emit sendImage(imHelpers.mat2Image(this->currentImage) );
  //emit sendImage(QImage("d:/test.bmp"));
}
```

Comment: Could you post the complete code of class definition?

Comment: @Tay2510; I have updated with definition.

Comment: I think `imageReader` is the class you should provide with the code.

Comment: @Tay2510; I updated again with imageReader.

Comment: The compilers said *"error: no matching function for call to imageReader::sendImage(cv::Mat&, QImage)"* because your signal definition is `void sendImage(QImage &imgQImage);` You cannot connect to a signal that doesn't even exist.

Comment: Like i said in question; i removed the cv::mat from signal,slot and connection in case error related to opencv. Current error is;  "error: no matching function for call to 'imageReader::sendImage(QImage)'"

Comment: where do you emit the signal? can you post that code too?

Comment: @m.s.; I updated again with signal calling.

Comment: @bmeric Show us where you `QObject::connect`. Also show us the `*.pro` file.

Comment: It would be great if you provide us a part of code where do you call `connect` function for this signal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I opened an issue in [bugreports.qt.io](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-45751) and looks like problem is related to Visual Studio. You can find details in [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-45751).

Edit: When i say "problem is related visual studio" i mean "Visual Studio lead me in the wrong direction", my emit line should give compile error in the first place like gcc.

Comment: No, as the developers told you in the bug report, the bug is that your signal should have a QImage parameter, not a QImage& parameter. It works in Visual Studio but shouldn't. It doesn't work in gcc which is why you have trouble on Android.